# Eclipseで、JSPのスクリプトレットの構文エラーを表示したいです。

Tags: eclipse, jsp

Eclipseで、JSPのスクリプトレットのコンパイルエラーを表示する方法を教えてください。
バージョンはEclipse 4.4のPleiadesです。
下記サイトから「UltimateのFull Edition]を選びました。
http://mergedoc.osdn.jp/index.html#/pleiades_distros4.4.html

下記のコードのように、スクリプトレットで変数名のつづり間違いがあった場合、
私のEclipseでは「エラー」と表示されません。

```
<%
String sample = "test";
System.out.println(sampel);
%>
```

そのため、「画面表示→エラーに気づく→修正」というステップを、いつも繰り返しています。
しかし、このやり方では効率が悪いように思います。

Comment: JavaプロジェクトにJSPを作成してコードを張り付けてみましたが、エラーは表示されました(エディタ上で赤線が出てカーソルを合わせると「sampelを変数に解決できません」と表示される）。プロジェクトのタイプがJava以外になっているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: プロジェクトのタイプは、Eclipseのどこから確認できるでしょうか？

Comment: Javaプロジェクトの場合、パッケージ・エクスプローラとかでプロジェクトのアイコンの右上にJが付きます。

Answer (score 0):

JSPエディター(などのJSP用のエディター)でファイルを開いていないだけではないでしょうか？

JSPファイルを右クリックして、「アプリケーションから開く」> 「JSP エディター」を選択しても結果は変わらないですか？